# Regex to match words after dot until a whitespace occurs

Tags: regex

Given the following string

```
span.a.b this.is.really.confusing
```

I need to return the matches `a` and `b`. I've been able to get close with the following regex:

```
(?<=\.)[\w]+
```

But it's also matching `is`, `really`, and `confusing`. When I include a negative lookahead I get even closer, but I'm still not there.

```
(?<=\.)[\w]+(?=\s) # matches b, confusing
```

How can I match words after a dot until a whitespace occurs?

Comment: I'm currently using Elixir to write this regex. http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Regex.html

Comment: According to that link, regex in Elixir are based on Perl; and according to RegexBuddy, Perl doesn't support repetitions inside a lookbehind. So I would try truncating the string first, and then using the regex.

Comment: Thank you the quick response. Currently I am using a `String.split\2` function to fix this problem temporarily

Comment: `words after a dot until a whitespace occurs` should only match `b` and `confusing`. Can you please clarify your condition as to why it should match `a` and not `confusing`?

Answer (score 0):

*How can I match words after a dot until a whitespace occurs?*
NB: this is language agnostic pseudo-code, but should work.

```
regex = "^[^\s.]+.(\S+).*"
targets = <extracted_group>.split(".")
```

Regex explanation:
"^": beings with
"[^\s.]+." 1 or more non-whitespace, non-period characters, followed by a period.
"(\S+)": group and capture all of the following non-whitespace characters
".*": matches 0 or more of any non-newline character

If the split function takes a regex instead of a string, you'll need to escape the '.' or use a character class.

NB: You can do it without the split, but I think that the split is more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is good enough for all your possible cases, but it should work with the provided example:

```
\.([\w]+)\.([\w]+)\s
```

$1 = a, $2 = b